# Automatically converting or updating SQL Server tables to XSD schema entities

Tags: sql-server, xsd

Can somebody guide me a tool which can convert a SQL Server table into XSD schema automatically.

I need to have a simple schema and doesn't need typed dataset as it's pretty heavy and doesn't fit my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use FOR XML syntax with AUTO, ELEMENTS and XMLSCHEMA:

SELECT * FROM table FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, XMLSCHEMA('tablexsd')

Comment: This is also giving me the data so can we remove it in the same script?